# make image double size and still clear?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, image

Any C/OC library to make a image double size and still clear as before?
I mean double size not zoom in,not just make frame double.

Comment: So you want to pad the image with a single color to double the size?

Comment: Not possible unless it is a vector image.

Comment: If you could do that, you would be rich.  You can't just fabricate pixel data out of thin air.  There are algorithms that can get close, but they are not realtime and usually only available to forensic scientists.